# Waterflow simulation through a pipe using Three.js

Tags: reactjs, three.js

I want to simulate water flow through the pipe using Three.js in my React application. As you can see in the below picture, I want to achieve three functionalities,

1. Draw a pipe
2. Simulate water based on % (0-100) - Now pipe filled with 70% of water.(user-defined)
3. Animate water flow using arrows moving from left to right - (left to right/ right to left) - user-defined

[image]

Something I tried was not working

Comment: Too many things in one question. I would start with the first one: to draw a hollow cylinder. For that, `ExtrudeGeometry` for a shape of circle with the circle hole, would be an option. Another option is `LatheGeometry`.

Comment: Hi,did you succeed ? I would like to do excatly the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hollow cylinder (pipe), based on `ExtrudeGeometry`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133.1";
import {
  OrbitControls
} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.133.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0x404040);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
light.position.setScalar(1);
scene.add(light, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

let r = 1, R = 1.25;

// pipe
let pipeShape = new THREE.Shape();
pipeShape.absarc(0, 0, R, 0, Math.PI * 2);
pipeShape.holes.push(new THREE.Path().absarc(0, 0, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, true));
let pipeGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(pipeShape, {
    curveSegments: 100,
    depth: 10,
    bevelEnabled: false
});
pipeGeometry.center();
let pipeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: "silver"});
let pipe = new THREE.Mesh(pipeGeometry, pipeMaterial);
scene.add(pipe);


window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);

renderer.setAnimationLoop(_ => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})

function onResize(event) {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
}

</script>
```

Comment: I am able to animate the flow direction from some documentation. Any idea for water simulation inside the tube would be really helpful

Comment: @Jerry For flow direction, I would use an animated texture with arrows. For water simulation, depends on your final goal, but I would start with `ExtrudeGeometry`. You can create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your cylinder Geometry is oversized compared to your scene.

Watch the following example :
https://codepen.io/freddy-turtle/pen/OJjVmvG?editors=1010

the cylinder appear in the whole screen with `CylinderGeometry = 1,1,3` as first arguments.

Comment: intentionally removed the code to avoid the confusion